# Did I understand the third conditional correctly?

Tags: conditional-constructions

All of these are sentences I would like write in the `Third Conditional`:

> 1: I would have gone by taxi, if I had had enough money.
>       2: He gladly would have taken his children for a walk, if he had been not so busy.
>       3: A traffic policeman would have found it sooner or later, if you had parked your car in       the wrong    place.
>       4: They would have made so many mistakes, if they had been attentive.
>       5: She would have let me know, if she had received.

If I didn't understand correctly, would you please correct me.

Comment: #2 should be '... if he had not been so busy'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the "third conditional" appears to be faultless.

There are however two errors of different kinds, which may be merely typos:

- In #4, you appear to have omitted *not*: *They would **not** have made so many mistakes...*
- In #5, *receive* is a transitive verb and requires a direct object: *She would have let me know if she had received **it***.

Comment: Not to disagree, but how would you handle the phrase "it is better to give than to receive", which contains no direct object?

Comment: @Rookatu The infinitives there are employed without arguments as nominals, not as constituents of clauses.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Are you saying that "to give" and "to receive" are acting as names of some sort? I certainly agree that they have no arguments (that was essentially my point). Put differently, if asked about what Joe likes to do, could one not respond "he likes to receive" without needing to specify a direct object (put aside for the moment that the verb is arguably passive, and therefore not "done")?

Comment: @Rookatu No, they are acting as noun-like forms.

Comment: I thought you might be saying something of the sort, but surely one couldn't correctly utter the phrase "it is better banana than silverware", right?

Comment: @No, but you may say "To give is better than to receive", just as you may say "A banana is better than silverware".

Comment: Gotcha ;) Well wishes.